# how to stop wifi scan on android?

Tags: android, wifi

Is it possible to stop wifi scan started with wifiMgr.startScan() ? I browse some posts and read about using thread to give intervals between each result delivery. But if I want to completely stop the process, how can I achieve it?

Comment: My wild guess would that it only runs for a little bit and then returns the results, it probably doesn't just run forever. That's a total guess though.

Comment: no, it runs continuously. i don't measure the interval, but having read this source code, http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/settings/wifi/WifiSettings.java.html i think there are some parameters affecting the update interval. so maybe it is not possible to completely stop the process. well, i hope i'm right.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer a few days ago. Simply unregister the receiver. I don't know if it is the best way to go, but it works.

Comment: Have you tried SO search feature? I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529276/android-how-to-unregister-a-receiver-created-in-the-manifest) :-)

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  Unregistering the receiver simply means you're ignoring the scan results, not stopping the scan.  If you re-register the receiver *without* calling startScan again, you'll see the scan results are still flowing in.  (At least that's what I'm seeing on a 4.3 device)

Comment: wirbly you are correct. I posted a question about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390414/android-wifimanager-and-scanning-battery-performance

Comment: Doesnt solve my problem. I want to STOP the scan because it appears to be causing conflicts with scanning for Bluetooth LE devices. Unregistering the receiver only stops one getting the results! The scan keeps going.

Answer (score 0):

I have found abortBroadcast(); to work. The strange thing is that I did not need to stop it initially as it only ran once each time I called startscan.