# Android app lifetime: maybe it infinite?

Tags: android, android-activity, alarmmanager, lifetime, android-wake-lock

I'm developing an app designed to transform an android phone into a remote device running without user action. At the time the app is made by an Activity that sets AlarmManager to execute a service (class inside project) every X minutes.

All this works OK, but occasionally **after 5-6 DAYS continuosly running** the application crashes (currently I don't know why, because i can't get the phone now). It isn't a connection problem (I know) and the phone is still running (plugged into AC). The only thing that i can suppose is that the application is down.

I don't think that this is due to a bug, because the prew debugging doesn't give me any errors.

So I must suppose that android has killed the activity (system needs more memory?) and as the image explain there is no way to back it up.

[image: Flow diagram]

But I have a doubt: in my application the activity doesn't matter, because all the work is done by the service.  The service itself is called by an Alarm Manager and in the time between two calls the service is terminated by StopSelf().

In my case the system may kill my alarm manager service schedule?

**What can I do to have the service start up by Alarm Manager forever?**

(*ATTENTION*: currently there is yet a WAKE LOCK but this consider only the execution of the service! I hope that you have understand that the service is called each x minutes by alarm manager and than terminated...i want to perform this operations for an indefinite time)

[I haven't posted the source code because is too long]

Comment: Get the phone, read the log, find out why it crashes. Instead of all the assumptions you have made in your question. It's actually unanswerable.

Comment: @BlundellPlease trust me...The phone is on a roof 12 km from here. I can't get the phone now! My assumptions are true beacuse the app comunicate witha server and so i know that the last battery level is 100% (=> no power problem) and the app worked for 5 days perfect sending info each 5 minutes (=> no app's bugs). So the only problem is due to android OS that had killed my app (or my alarm manager?!?) That's the question...@Matt Clarkson the problem is that android OS killed something because the alarm manager doesn't lunch more the service. Thanx

Comment: And why did you send the phone to a roof 12km away if the application has not been thoroughly tested ? Does it run in the emulator ?

Comment: @dtmilano Maybe that you have not read my whole question: it's 5 days running! I' did a test at home 24 hours long with no problem. That's because i have installed it on a roof for the work as it is designed to. This problem it's very different from normal android app problems...Se sei italiano posso spiegarti meglio!

Comment: So get it on another device and reproduce the error. You *NEED* to know what that error was.

Comment: Maybe there isn't any kind of error? When android OS terminate an activty, it deletes also AlarmManager schedule to Service?

Comment: "When android OS terminate an activty, it deletes also AlarmManager schedule to Service?" -- no. The only things that I know of that delete an AlarmManager schedule are a force-stop by the user, a reboot, or you deleting the alarm yourself. However, please understand that Android is not designed to run unattended for days at a time. Android is not a server.

Comment: Thanx, that's the problem: who deleted the alarm manager? Android maybe is not design to do this, but remember that is a calculator...and my app don't make it a server, but a client!!!

Answer (score 4):

Lork,

After wrestling with a similar issues myself, I may have some pointers for you. I assume that you are using your Android device as a sort of remote ‘embedded controller’, which performs its functions with minimum user interaction. I believe that you are 95% there and just need to make some slight architectural changes. As you have not provided code, I’ll just explain in abstract terms rather than give code examples.

CommonsWare is correct that you need to use AlarmManager, but I suspect you already knew that. 
A couple of background comments first, just to make sure that everything is understandable. 
Alarms created by AlarmManager exist at the system level, that is they can exist beyond the lifecycle of the activity and application that created them. If you set an alarm but don’t want it to go off if your app changes state (for example after it has been destroyed), then you can cancel it using alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent) – just create the intents and alarm manager with the same parameters and Android will match the alarm).
Similarly, BroadcastReceivers are registered at the system level (at least if they are declared in manifest.xml) and can exist beyond the lifecycle of the activity and application that created them. Again if you want to ensure that a BroadcastReceiver does not fire in response to an event occurring after your app has changed state (for example after it has been destroyed), you need to explicitly unregister in it code. If it was registered programmatically then use context.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver); if it was registered statically in the Manifest its not so easy – you will have to retrieve the receiver using PackageManager and ComponentName (see: [Android - how to unregister a receiver created in the manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529276/android-how-to-unregister-a-receiver-created-in-the-manifest) ) - and remember that you will need to re-enable the receiver if you need it again.

You say you have already set up your alarm. Make sure you specify ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or RTC_WAKUP for the alarm Type to ensure that it runs even when the phone is in ‘sleep’ mode. 
You also say you have already created the associated BroadcastReceiver to handle to alarm event. The BroadcastReceiver should do a minimum of work, so you should handle any processing in a separate thread or by launching a Service. You opted to launch a Service and terminate it using stopSelf() when it has finished, so that it doesn’t use up system resources. So far so good.

This is fine when the app is running, however as you require something that runs reliably for an indefinite period, you need to ensure that you manage the 'exception' situations where it has paused, the device is ‘sleeping’, the app has crashed/terminated, or the device has rebooted (and any other exception scenarios you may think of). Here are the issues I have identified that you need to address:

First: WakeLock is only guaranteed for the duration of the onReceive() method of the BroadcastReceiver. After it has terminated, the device could go back to ‘sleep’ even if your Service has not started or even completed, so you need to create a WakeLock, pass it to the Service and release it before you stop the Service.  (Note: for your application, you require a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK). Be very careful using WakeLocks – make sure you only hold a WakeLock for the minimum required time and ensure you release it, as it’s use can lead to excessive battery drain). See http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/power_management.html  for an example of using WakeLocks.

Second: If you reset your alarm in code (rather than defining an automatically repeating one), do this in the OnReceive() method of the BroadcastReceiver or as the first thing in the Service you have launched – this will ensure that the alarm repeats, irrespective of the state of the application or device.

Third: Make sure that any Contexts you use are going to be non-null values. You can dynamically fetch the context in the Service using getApplicationContext(). Otherwise this can be achieved by EXPLICITLY passing the Context from your application to the alarm and make sure it is passed all the way through the BroadcastReceiver, and associated threads and Services. If you have statically stored Context in your application so you can retrieve it anywhere, then this will return a null value if the application has terminated. If you use the Context (for example to retrieve a resource, access a database etc), and it is null, it will cause a null pointer exception and the Service or BroadcastReceiver will crash. I believe this is the most likely reason for your Broadcast receivers not to be working when your app has terminated.

Fourth: You may wish to make references to ResourceIDs (e.g. R.drawable.icon) in your Service or BroadcastReceiver fully qualified (. R.drawable.icon) or generated from the passed Context. I haven’t yet found this to be necessary, but I suspect it may be prudent.

Fifth: Implement a separate BroadcastReceiver to handle a device reboot scenario (ON_BOOT_COMPLETE event). You could get this receiver to re-launch the app if appropriate or it could launch a service to check that your app is supposed to be active, set up any required parameters and set up the relevant alarms, then terminate it using stopSelf(), or just set the alarm again and let that receiver handle it all. Remember to ensure the service has a WakeLock for its duration and to release the WakeLock when it is complete. If you don’t just relaunch the app, or a Service (declared as part of your application) then you should also statically store the correct Context as a class attribute in your BroadcastReceiver, if you need it, so that it is available to access resources.

A couple of other things you may wish to consider: 
As your set up is remote, I would seriously consider storing any persistent data in SQLite database tables. This will ensure that data is recoverable between application terminations and device reboots, without having to regenerate it.
If your application communicates with a server service, consider using push notifications for server initiated communication, rather than have the app periodically poll. Push Notifications can also be used to ‘wake up and launch services and apps’, so could be used as part of a remote mechanism to query the status of the device and your application. This approach is also more power efficient and timely.
Post information to LogCat at key points in your code for debugging. If the application terminates, then adb stops tracking the source code running for the receiver and service, but LogCat continues to function, so can be used to check the path through the code and variable values.

Other people may have better ways to address these issues or some other pointers (I would certainly be very happy to see other input), but I hope these ideas are helpful and good luck!

Comment: What difference will it make if the it Alram.setRepeating() or in the service set the alarm.set()?

Comment: great answer for a vague question

Answer (score 0):

The point behind using `AlarmManager` with a service is to start up a service that will run briefly, then the service goes away (e.g., an `IntentService`). If you are going to try to have an everlasting service, you do not need `AlarmManager`, and your service *will* be shut down by Android after some period of time.

If you rewrite your app to *not* need an everlasting service, but rather use `AlarmManager` as it was intended, you should have better survivability.

Comment: Thanx but the point isn't this. I don't want an "everlasting service". In fact my service mustbe terminated at the endo of operation (each X minutes). I need that AlarmManager continues to call service forever!!!

Comment: You asked "What can I do to have the application (the service) to run for an indefinte amount of time?". Now you are saying that the service does not run for an indefinite amount of time.

Comment: "The point behind using AlarmManager with a service is to start up a service that will run briefly, then the service goes away" That's exactly wath is doing my app but after 5-6 days alarmmanager stops to start up service!!! why?

Comment: In the txt you quote is not clear (sorry but im not english) In my prew message i have explained it better..

Comment: Please CommonsWare help me and don't delete your answer as you do it last week on one my question..

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what Lork wants to achieve is similar to something I am also wrestling with.
He wants the alarm manager to trigger a broadcast receiver that will handle the alarm, even when the application it is part of, has been terminated (for example by the Android OS).

For example: The application sets an alarm, with a type of ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or RTC_WAKUP and has a Broadcast Receiver to handle it when it fires, via an Intent which references the application context and the Broadcast receiver class. The receiver is declared as a  in the application manifest.

Under normal circumstances, when the application is running or paused, when the alarm goes off, the Broadcast Receiver is triggered, waking up the device and resuming the application as necessary, and the alarm in handled.
However, if the application has been killed (for example by the OS), then the alarm will still go off (as it is still registered) but the Broadcast Receiver will not be triggered and LogCat shows a null pointer exception, (I assume because the reference to the application is no longer in memory). This will occur, even if the Context has been passed.

Am I (and I assume Lork) missing an easy strategy here? Or is it not possible? Can a broadcast receiver exist on its own and trigger the app if necessary?

One, imperfect strategy I have been toying with, is to move all the app data access into a Content Provider, and have a separate low profile app which just implements the broadcast receiver – triggering a service to do the work and accessing the application data it requires via the Content Provider. This would still be subject to being terminated by the OS, but would be less likely.

Comment: Was just reading, and I like the amount of effort @David has put to explain. +1 just for that.