# How to unregister BroadcastReceiver from Activity

Tags: android, exception, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

It's probably a very simple question but I seem to be hung up on these from a day. So here is the question:

How to unregister a BroadcastReceiver in Activity which was registered from AndroidManifest file?
Here is the code::

```
 <receiver  android:name=".PhoneCallReceiver">
        <intent-filter  >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I am familiar with the function

> public void unregisterReceiver (BroadcastReceiver receiver)

but it throws an exception if not registered from that Activity with

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
registerReceiver(mybroadcast, filter);
```

Comment: Try unregistering it from the application object.  I think that receivers in the manifest are registered in the application.

Comment: @GabeSechan-I dont get it...can u provide me with some code..??

Comment: getApplication().unregisterReceiver(receiver);  The Application object also allows you to register a receiver and unregister it.  If you register a receiver via the manifest it becomes registered with the application context, not an activity context.

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid : see [Android - how to unregister a receiver created in the manifest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529276/android-how-to-unregister-a-receiver-created-in-the-manifest) post

Comment: @GabeSechan-It throws "me:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered" exception !!!

Comment: What would happen if I do not unregister the broadcast receiver? Would it remain active even after the phone reboots ?

Comment: @Jaydev, no it will not remain active after phone reboots. But android will give you warning to unregister it immediately after that activity's onPause is called. This is generally the best practice to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable a `receiver` that was defined in the `manifest`, use the following:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, PhoneCallReceiver.class)
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(component , PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED , PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: @iTech- Dont I need to mention which action receiver I need to unregister...for Eg: Here it is 'android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE' !!

Comment: You are specifying the receiver class `PhoneCallReceiver.class` which is sufficient to determine which receiver to disable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void onResume()
  {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    registerReceiver(mybroadcast, filter);  

  }

  public void onPause()
  {
    unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
  }
```

Comment: I cant register it from Activity if I have registered it from AndroidManifest.xml !!