# Android Broadcastreceiver unregister needed when registered in manifest?

Tags: android, filter, broadcastreceiver

So mainly that is the question, when I register a `Broadcastreceiver` dynamically, it is needed to be unregistered at `onDestroy`. But when the `Broadcastreceiver` is registered within the manifest, do we need to unregister it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be careful while adding broadcast receiver because unnecessary `broadcast receivers` drain battery power.

If you add the broadcast receiver in the **Android manifest file**, it’s implied that you are going to handle a particular intent in the broadcast receiver and not ignore it.

You can use the `PackageManager` to enable/disable a `BroadcastReceiver` in declared in the Manifest. The `Broadcast Receiver` will get fired only when it is enabled.

For more info see [Android - how to unregister a receiver created in the manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529276/android-how-to-unregister-a-receiver-created-in-the-manifest)

There is a way to enable and disable the broadcast receiver which is added in the manifest file.

See this post [Android broadcast receiver: Registering/unregistering during runtime](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/android-broadcast-receiver-enable-and.html)

Comment: True about the battery! So yes, I am using one with a Bluetooth connection, but my app has several activities. When registering in a dynamical way it seems to stop when other activity than the main one starts, but when registered in manifest it works perfect. But it keeps on even after `onDestroy` happens. I was planning to disable them at `onDestroy`. Your links are quite useful by the way!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot unregister a manifest-registered receiver. If the receiver is enabled, it will always be listening for broadcasts.

Comment: kindly please, can u tell me how to set the manifest-registered receiver to be disabled? i tried android:enabled="false" and in onStrat() i checked if the receiver is enabled or not, but i found that it is always in the COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT

Comment: @user2121: Well, `android:enabled="false"` should work. You can change it programmatically by calling `setComponentEnabledSetting()` on `PackageManager`.