# Unregister Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android

I making a app in which a broadcast receiver run regularly even when application is close. My app is working very well but when i want to unregister my Broadcast Receiver it gave me error that "receiver is not registered". I write its entry on the manifest file as this

```android
<receiver  android:name=".PhoneCallReceiver">
            <intent-filter  android:priority="10" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: *Stop* trying to make every question you write bold. It's ugly, bad form, and illegible.

Comment: @J. Steen, Stop use italic :) do not swear, friends

Comment: @TapaSave Why? I'm using it for brief emphasis. And since when is it swearing?

Comment: @J. Steen, This is joke

Comment: I so sorry sir for all this. Actually i am new in stack overflow and i don't known many rules of this website but i am extremely so sorry if i hurt you and your feeling. Please forgive me and my mistake

Comment: And Thank you so much to teach a lesson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `unregisterReceiver()` to unregister something that you registered in the manifest. Use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to indicate whether this `<receiver>` is enabled or not -- if it is not enabled, it will not longer respond to broadcasts.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6529365:

```
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, MyReceiver.class);
Check if the Component is enabled or disabled

int status = context.getPackageManager().getComponentEnabledSetting(component);
if(status PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED) {
Log.d("receiver is enabled");
} else if(status PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED) {
Log.d("receiver is disabled");
}
Enable/Disable the component(Broadcast Receiver in your case)

//Disable
context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED , PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
//Enable
context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED , PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. You save my lot of line of code.