# How to disable the broadcast Receiver to stop receiving the incoming calls?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am facing the issue in disable the broadcast receiver. The broadcast receiver receives the incoming and outgoing calls .
In my case when switch is in on the receiver should receive the data when the switch is in off the receiver should stop receiving the data.

```
     switches.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

//                sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("enableApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
//                editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.enable), isChecked);
//                editor.commit();


                if(isChecked)
                {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    PackageManager pm  = DashBoardActivity.this.getPackageManager();
                    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(DashBoardActivity.this, CallReceiver.class);
                    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            }
        });
```

This is my tried code , i tried to disable the broadcast receiver by using the package manager.

```
The broadcast receiver registered in manifestfile
     <receiver android:name=".receiver.CallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I want to disable the receiver in my activity.How to disable the receiver ?

Comment: you can get help from here :-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529276/android-how-to-unregister-a-receiver-created-in-the-manifest

Comment: what your toast showing when you disabled the receiver?

Comment: I tried that answer ..but not solved my problem

Comment: @ Sandeep dhiman when the switched off condition toast message cancelled is viewing

Comment: check status of your receiver and show  it in toast if it got disabled it will show disabled int status = context.getPackageManager().getComponentEnabledSetting(component);

Comment: @Sandeep dhiman  Broadcast status: 2 is showing the toast.

Comment: @Sandeep dhiman  this message "Discarding data. Failed to send event to service" shown in logcat

Comment: status 2 means you have disabled your receiver

Comment: @ Sandeep dhiman If i disabled the receiver means,the data receiviing should be stopped but the data is still receiving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, the below code could solve your problem,

```
 switches.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

            sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("enableApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.enable), isChecked);
            editor.commit();


            if(isChecked)
            {
                PackageManager pm  = DashBoardActivity.this.getPackageManager();
                ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(DashBoardActivity.this, CallReceiver.class);
                int status = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getComponentEnabledSetting(componentName);
                pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
                Log.e("Broadcast status",status + "");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
            else
            {


                PackageManager pm  = DashBoardActivity.this.getPackageManager();
                ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(DashBoardActivity.this, CallReceiver.class);
                int status = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getComponentEnabledSetting(componentName);
                pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
                Log.e("Broadcast status",status + "");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }
    });
```