# Google Play Services location API: how to receive broadcast messages on enable/disable?

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, broadcast

I am trying to get notifications when the user enables/disables location services. I know that I can do this by using the `android.location.LocationManager` API

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#MODE_CHANGED_ACTION

or

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION

But I cannot find an equivalent using the Google Play Services location API.

I **can** use `checkLocationSettings` to see the current settings and display a dialog to resolve them if necessary. But without the option to register a receiver/listener, I have to write a polling loop for this call, which is a lot of wasted effort.

The package summary for `android.location` 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary says:

> The Google Location Services API, part of Google Play services, is the preferred way to add location-awareness to your app. It offers a simpler API, higher accuracy, low-power geofencing, and more.

So surely there should be a simpler API to get programmatic notifications of location services enable/disable using Google Location Services than the default `android.location.LocationManager`?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you checked this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691894/how-to-disable-the-broadcast-receiver-to-stop-receiving-the-incoming-calls)?

Comment: I don't think that is very related. First, it is related to phone calls and not to location tracking (e.g. `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`). And second, it looks like the OP wants to disable a broadcast receiver registered in the manifest based on a switch in their activity (i.e. `DashboardActivity`). In my case, I want to (always) receive notifications of user changes directly to the location settings in the settings app.