# Android How to use checkbox for enable/disable start app on device boot?

Tags: android, checkbox, boot

i want to add checkbox to start my app on device boot

This is what i tried :

Step 1: Set the permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Step 2: Add this intent filter in receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Step 3: in BootReceiver.java

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import static com.example.myapp.MainActivity.Global.*;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (preferences.getBoolean( "boot", false )) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent( context, SplashScreen.class );
            myIntent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
            context.startActivity( myIntent );
        }
    }
}
```

4. In MainActivity.java Before onCreat:

> ```
> public static class Global {
> public static SharedPreferences preferences;
> }
> CheckBox AutoBoot;
> ```

5. In MainActivity.java in onCreat:

> ```
> preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( this );
>         final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
>
> if (preferences.getBoolean( "boot", false )) {
> AutoBoot.setChecked( true );
> } else {
> AutoBoot.setChecked( false );
> }
>
> AutoBoot.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
>                 if (isChecked) {
>                     editor.putBoolean( "boot", true );
>                     editor.apply();
>                 } else {
>                     editor.putBoolean( "boot", false );
>                     editor.apply();
>                 }
>             }
>         } );
> ```

Comment: [MJ Studio's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57762941) is spot on. There is not going to be a `MainActivity` instance at boot, so `preferences` is going to be null. You really don't want to use `static` members like that, anyway. All you need to access `SharedPreferences` is a `Context`, and one is passed into `onReceive()` in your `BroadcastReceiver`. Also, a more efficient method to toggle your app's boot response would be to enable/disable that Receiver altogether, as appropriate. You can see examples of how to do that in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6529276.

Comment: Thanks, i did as in your link and all works fine !

Answer (score 0):

is there NPE in preferences? Your initialization code of preferences static variable is in MainActivity instance. So if you use it in BroadcastReceiver, It may cause NpE

Comment: Right there was NPE in preferences but now it's ok by using Mike M link for enabling disabling Receiver.

Comment: ah i see thanx!